# How to trigger change event of slider on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

> I have a jQuery slider. I have two buttons i.e ZoomIn and ZoomOut. I want to slide the slider on these button click. Like by clicking ZoomIn it should slide towards right and by clicking ZoomOut it should slide towards left, and should call their respective slide function/event too.

[Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rbW35/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#zoomSlider").slider({
        min: -3.32,
        max: 4.00,
        step: 0.01,
        value: 0.1,
        animate: false,
            "slide": function (event, ui) {
            $("#zoom").val(ui.value + "%");
        }
    });

    $("#zoom").val($("#zoomSlider").slider("value") + "%");
});
```

> **Updated**
> I also need a function to be called when slider changes. That function take two parameters 1)event 2)ui, how to get those parameteters when button click ? like :

```
$('#zoomIn').on('click', function () {

    if (counter < 4.00) {//if counter less than max value
        counter += .1;//increment counter
        $slider.slider("value", counter)
        $("#zoom").val($slider.slider("value") + "%");
        myFunction(event, ui);
    }
});
```

Comment: what does this myFunction do?

Comment: this function make the svg zoom and do lot more things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var counter = 0, //initialize counter
    $slider = $("#zoomSlider");

$slider.slider({
    min: -3.32,
    max: 4.00,
    step: 0.01,
    value: 0.1,
    animate: false,
    "slide": function (event, ui) {
        $("#zoom").val(ui.value + "%");
        counter = ui.value; //change counter value if user slides

    }
});
$("#zoom").val($slider.slider("value") + "%");

counter = $slider.slider("value"); // set slider value in counter

$('#zoomIn').on('click', function () {

    if (counter < 4.00) { //if counter less than max value
        counter += .1; //increment counter
        $slider.slider("value", counter)
        $("#zoom").val($slider.slider("value") + "%");
    }
});

$('#zoomOut').on('click', function () {
    if (counter > -3.32) { //if counter greater than min value
        counter -= .1; //decrement counter
        $slider.slider("value", counter)
        $("#zoom").val($slider.slider("value") + "%");
    }
});
```

});

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/rbW35/5/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       

          $("#zoomIn").click(function (){ 

          var current = $( "#zoom" ).val().slice(0,-1);
          var new_position =  (parseFloat(current)+0.1) ;             
              $("#zoom").val( new_position +"%"); 
              $("#zoomSlider").slider('value',new_position);                        
              $( "#zoom" ).val( $( "#zoomSlider" ).slider( "value" )+"%" );});

          $("#zoomOut").click(function (){ 

              var current = $( "#zoom" ).val().slice(0,-1);
              var new_position_out =  (parseFloat(current)-0.1) ;                
                 $("#zoom").val( new_position_out +"%"); 
                 $("#zoomSlider").slider('value',new_position_out);                        
                 $( "#zoom" ).val( $( "#zoomSlider" ).slider( "value" )+"%" );});
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jagruti/F5Khn/)

Answer (score 0):

Example similar to what you want exists in official [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms). [Slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) event is only for mouse manipulation on slider, use [change](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) to capture slider changes. Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbW35/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $("#zoomSlider"),
        counter = $("#zoom");

    slider.slider({
        min: -3.32,
        max: 4.00,
        step: 0.01,
        value: 0.1,
        animate: false,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            counter.val(ui.value.toFixed(2) + "%");
        }
    });

    counter.val(slider.slider("value").toFixed(2) + "%");

    $('[type="button"]').on('click', function (event) {
        var el = $(event.currentTarget),
            mult = el.data().negative ? 1 : -1;

        slider.slider("value", slider.slider("value") + slider.slider("option", "step") * mult);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rbW35/1/)

We first get the current value of the slider. Then, we set the slider value to the current value minus one.

```
$('#zoomOut').click(function() {
    var current_value = $('#zoomSlider').slider('option','value');
    $("#zoomSlider").slider("value", current_value-=1);
});
```

If you want the have the slider animate as it's changing value, you can change the "animate" parameter to "true" in the creation of the slider.